# How to drow this kind of histogram

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have this data

```
               blue_values    Green_values
XGB                 11              45
TF(1k ex/l)         32             120
TF(5k ex/l)        240             650
```

and I would like to drow a histogram similar to this form. I need a python code :
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: You could use matplotlib and [this site](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/histogram_path.html?highlight=histogram)

Comment: I have tried many codes but they didn ' t get me the same as this picture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [seaborn bar chart for categorical data, grouped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067785/seaborn-bar-chart-for-categorical-data-grouped)

Comment: Thank for your help Anderson it is really useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the plot function of pandas. Here is one solution.

```
# Module import
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DataFrame definiton
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[11,  45],
     [32,  120],
     [240, 650]], 
     columns=["blue_values",  "Green_values"],             
    index=["XGB", "TF(1k ex/l)", "TF(5k ex/l)"])

print(df)
#              blue_values  Green_values
# XGB                   11            45
# TF(1k ex/l)           32           120
# TF(5k ex/l)          240           650

# Build plot + custum color
df.plot.bar(colors=["#4C72B0", "#55A868"], rot=0, title="Training Time")

# Y label
plt.ylabel("Time [s]")

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

`rot=0` is used for horizontal x label.

[image: abel]